# Jena simple example java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jena

I have tried this simple example and after hours spent still can not resolve the problem. I was wondering if anyone has any idea?

```
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.*;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.*;

/** Tutorial 1 creating a simple model
*/

public class Tutorial01 extends Object {
    // some definitions
    static String personURI    = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith";
    static String fullName     = "John Smith";

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    // create an empty model
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

   // create the resource
   Resource johnSmith = model.createResource(personURI);

  // add the property
  johnSmith.addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName);
  }
}
```

After running the program..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory
at jena.Tutorial01.main(Tutorial01.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Comment: The classpath at runtime does not include the Jena jars. Ideally, use an ID with maven to sort this out automatically; if using the command line, remember to use "-cp" with `<Dir>\lib\*`, <Dir> being the Jena installation.